# Postfix auto create maildir

Tags: email, postfix-mta, inbox

I'm trying to config virtual mailboxes on postfix..

My virtual configuration looks like this:

```
#myhostname =
#alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
#alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = localhost, localhost.cz
#relayhost =
#mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 31.31.72.249/8
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all

mailbox_size_limit = 0

virtual_transport = virtual
virtual_minimum_uid = 1000
virtual_alias_domains =
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/home/postfix/aliases.cf, mysql:/home/postfix/emails.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/home/postfix/domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/home/postfix/mailbox.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
```

But when I recieve an email, I get error:

Sep 11 16:48:02 asianstyle postfix/virtual[23228]: EC38A3F693: to=, relay=virtual, delay=0.06, delays=0.03/0.02/0/0.01, dsn=4.2.0, status=deferred (delivery failed to mailbox /var/vmail/asianstyle.cz/info/inbox: unable to create lock file /var/vmail/asianstyle.cz/info/inbox.lock: No such file or directory)

Folder /var/vmail exists and belongs to vmail:vmail (which has uid and gid 5000)
Do I have to create directories manually or can postfix create them and I have just some missconfiguration?

Thank you for any help..

Comment: I'm having the same problem but i'm a beginner in email servers administration. 

I dont think the postfix delivery agent can do that. I passed the mail to another programm that handles this (example dovecotLDA with autocreate_maildir). Did you solve the problem ?